# Inefficent Query Plans SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

Good Day,

We experience ongoing issues with our databases for which our internal DBA's are unable to explain.

Using the below query example:

```
Select Distinct
   Date,
   AccountNumber,
   Region,
   Discount,
   ActiveBalance
Into 
   #sometemptable
From 
   anothertable With (Index(ondate)) --use this or the query takes much longer
Where 
   Date >='7/1/2013'
   And ActiveBalance > 0
   And Discount <> '0' and discount is not null
```

This query will often run for an hour plus before I end up needing to kill it.

However, if I run the query as follows:

```
Select Distinct
   Date,
   AccountNumber,
   Region,
   Discount,
   ActiveBalance
Into 
   #sometemptable
From 
   anothertable With (Index(ondate)) --use this or the query takes much longer
Where 
   Date Between '7/1/2013' and '12/1/2013'  --all of the dates are the first of the month
   And ActiveBalance > 0
   And Discount <> '0' and discount is not null
```

Followed by

```
Insert into #sometemptable
   Select Distinct
      Date,
      AccountNumber,
      Region,
      Discount,
      ActiveBalance
   From 
      anothertable With (Index(ondate)) --use this or the query takes much longer
   Where 
      Date Between '1/1/2014' and '6/1/2014'  --all of the dates are the first of the month
      And ActiveBalance > 0
      And Discount <> '0' and discount is not null
```

I can run the query in less than 10 minutes. The particular tables I'm hitting are updated monthly. Stat updates are run on these tables both Monthly and weekly. Our DBA's, as mentioned before do not understand why the top query takes so much longer than the combination of the smaller queries.

Any ideas? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Ron

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the execution plans?

Comment: I'll work at that Dave.  I typically have to kill the longer query due to the time it takes to run.  I do have the XML version of one of the shorter ones.  Once I get them, I'll up them.  Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Have you checked the execution plans? You can also display the estimated plan without running the query. Also, are you sure your statistics are up to date?

Comment: Stats are updated weekly and monthly on the table being used.  As far as the execution plans go, was thrown into SQL with no actual training on the plans, etc.  However it does appear the the majority of the resources being used are on an index which is not required.  I only have limited rights on the server and this particular index is used for other things.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but when you do `Date >= '7/1/2013'` sql will analyze how many rows it will approximatly return, and if the rows are greater then some internal threshold it will do a scan instead of a seek, thinking that there is enough data that it needs to return that a a scan will be faster.

When you do the between clause, sql server will do a seek because it knows it will not need to return the majority of rows that, that table has.

I assume that it is doing a table scan when you do the >= search. Once you post the Execution plans we will see for sure.

Comment: I attempted to post the screenshot but apparently I do not have enough reputation to do so.  The majority of the time is spent on an index that really wasn't required.  Unfourtantely I have very limited access as to what I can do on the database (no admin rights).  The other issue we have, is now I've attempted to re-run my first smaller query (which took 3 minutes the first time).  Now its been running 27 minutes.  Another anomoly our internal DBA's have been unable to explain as there are no conflicting resources.  Don't know if anyone is able to provide any advice with my lack of info?